# How to throw exception to caller from async method?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await

Today I read a lot about async/await and it completely blew my mind.
I can't understand why the following test passed.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var listener = new AsyncHttpListener();
    listener.ListeningAsync();

    try
    {
        new WebClient().DownloadString("http://localhost:8080/");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    listener.Close();
}

public class AsyncHttpListener
{
    private readonly HttpListener listener;

    public AsyncHttpListener()
    {
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/");
        listener.Start();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        listener.Close();
    }

    public async void ListeningAsync()
    {
        var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
        HandleContext(context);
    }

    private void HandleContext(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        throw new Exception("test excpetion");
    }
}
```

Test passed, but output contains:

```
System.Exception
test excpetion
   at AsyncHttpListenerTest.AsyncHttpListener.HandleContext(HttpListenerContext context) in AsyncHttpListener.cs: line 30
   at AsyncHttpListenerTest.AsyncHttpListener.d__0.MoveNext() in AsyncHttpListener.cs: line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

I expect that exception will be transmitted from task thread (HandleContext() method) to caller context and test fail. How can i get this behavior?

Answer (score 13):

Make your method `async Task` instead of `async void`, and make your test method `async Task` instead of `void`:

```
public async Task ListeningAsync()
{
    var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
    HandleContext(context);
}

[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    var listener = new AsyncHttpListener();
    await listener.ListeningAsync();

    try
    {
        new WebClient().DownloadString("http://localhost:8080/");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    listener.Close();
}
```

There are several good reasons to avoid `async void`. Error handling is one of them. Errors raised from `async void` methods go straight to the `SynchronizationContext` that was current when the method started.

The reason your test passed is because `async` methods may return to their caller before they complete. The test runner sees the test method return (without throwing an exception yet), and marks it as "passed". If you return `Task` from your test method, then the test runner knows to wait for the `Task` to complete before considering the test complete.